# Finding Top value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

Instead of changing `top` value the way I know how to ie, `$('#div').css('top', 'VALUE')`. Are there any other methods to do this?

I'm creating a slider and on `window` `Resize` the next and previous buttons move set `top` `VALUE`.
 Changing it from `%` to `px` doesn't solve the issue.

Help I'm looking for is around this area: `if(!=$('#div').css('top' '50%')){ //keep value to 50% 
}`.

Sorry for my poor use of jQuery.

Thanks and I'd greatly appreciate anyone that can help me out.

Comment: if you want 50% why can't you just do it with css? You will need to provide more code if you want help. A demo in jsfiddle.net woul help also

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the top of an element is at 50% of the page height?

Comment: @CmdrTallen `if($('#div').css('top') > '50%'){}`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. First of all, jQuery is a really ineffective and glitchy solution for this kind of behavior so let's do this in CSS with `position:fixed`. It will result in the same mechanics but at a design level, which is more suitable for a position.

```
.fixed-box {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:15px;
    background:#f00;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hvL4C/)

Comment: Yeah I'd love to use CSS and i have done so. Since my div is in a div that has overflow hidden. position fixed moves the div with in that div when the page is resized

Comment: It moves it up because top value is a `%`

Answer (score 0):

not sure about what you exactly want, but if you simply want to get the css value you can simply do `$('#div').css('top')` and it willl give you whatever the value is..

Comment: no you are comparing a string to string, so this comparison would not work